# What is the build error I'm running into while working through the GAE bookshelf tutorial?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

For some broader context: I am wanting to move a react app that I have built and previously hosted through Firebase Hosting over to GAE to host it there so that I can connect to both my firebase and cloud postgresql databases (could not find a way to connect to cloud postgresql from my app hosted on Firebase).

Apologies in advance for the somewhat vague question, but I've run into several issues just working through the bookshelf app tutorial and have been able to work through some of the errors but have not been able to figure out the issue here:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build eaf3e253-ee83-46d4-a640-fd7e68083a13 status: FAILURE.
Build error details: {"error":{"errorType":"BuildError","canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"2BCB87EC","errorMessage":"INFO     FTL version node-v0.17.0\n
INFO     Beginning FTL build for node\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository us.gcr.io/piva-primero/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path \"\"\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: name us.gcr.io/piva-primero/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:55db4aec-8e29-42ea-bea3-c457808a429c\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache True\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: upload True\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: base us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_20191019_10_16_3_RC00\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt \n
INFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint None\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.gaeconfig\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv\n
INFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity NOTSET\n
INFO     starting: full build\n
INFO     starting: builder initialization\n
INFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_20191019_10_16_3_RC00'\n
INFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'us.gcr.io/piva-primero/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:55db4aec-8e29-42ea-bea3-c457808a429c'\n
INFO     builder initialization took 0 seconds\n
INFO     starting: build process for FTL image\n
INFO     starting: rm_node_modules\n
INFO     rm_node_modules rm -rf /workspace/node_modules\n
INFO     `rm_node_modules` stdout:\n\n
INFO     rm_node_modules took 0 seconds\n
INFO     using descriptor:package-lock.json\n
INFO     using descriptor:package.json\n
INFO     starting: checking_cached_packages_json_layer\nDEBUG    Checking cache for cache_key ddd19bc8f86cc8fedfd69dfce5aac6d21a6e2024dec42d6d3a96af6fc7a78dbd\n
INFO     No cached base image found for entry: us.gcr.io/piva-primero/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/node-cache:ddd19bc8f86cc8fedfd69dfce5aac6d21a6e2024dec42d6d3a96af6fc7a78dbd.\n
INFO     Cache miss on local cache for us.gcr.io/piva-primero/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/node-cache:ddd19bc8f86cc8fedfd69dfce5aac6d21a6e2024dec42d6d3a96af6fc7a78dbd\n
INFO     No cached dependency layer for ddd19bc8f86cc8fedfd69dfce5aac6d21a6e2024dec42d6d3a96af6fc7a78dbd\n
INFO     [CACHE][MISS] v0.17.0:NODE-\u003eddd19bc8f86cc8fedfd69dfce5aac6d21a6e2024dec42d6d3a96af6fc7a78dbd\n
INFO     checking_cached_packages_json_layer took 0 seconds\n
INFO     starting: building_packages_json_layer\n
INFO     starting: npm_install\n
INFO     npm_install npm install --production\n
INFO     `npm_install` stdout:\n\n\u
003e grpc@1.7.3 install /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc\n\u
003e node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library\n\n
make: Entering directory '/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc/build'\n
make: Entering directory '/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc/build'\n
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o\n
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o\n
grpc.target.mk:405: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o' failed\n
make: Leaving directory '/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc/build'\n
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o\n
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --modul.
```

I'm trying to run the tutorial code on my machine. I've been able to successfully deploy a different app in another project but have had some real trouble with this one. Any tips for resolving this error would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not an expert on React but familiar with Google Cloud Platform. Have you resolved this? If not, please include the package.json and, if possible, a minimal repro of the issue. The error suggests that Cloud Build is unable to `make` one of the dependencies for your project, specifically `@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc`. I'm going to try deploying something that uses that library. It's curious that the path includes what appear to be gRPC and I wonder whether that's an issue?

Comment: I assume App Engine standard (not flex).

Comment: I tried the simplest example using the Video Intelligence API and it builds, deploys and runs. Either an intermittent issue that's not currently a problem or something specific to your code.